# How to improve Intellij 8?

Tags: java, visual-studio, ide, intellisense, intellij-idea

Is there a way to improve the intellisense of intellij?  I love how visual Studio intellisense works by making suggestions as you type.

Answer (score 1):

That might be a good idea. To get that information you have to hit ctrl+space or ctrl+shft+space Having it automatic might be a good idea.

You can post the suggestion to http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/IDEA after registering and they should get back to you fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to "File:Settings" (or hit Ctrl-Alt-S), and find this panel:
[image]

Change the autopopup timings to whatever you prefer and be happy! :)

Comment: yeah... visual studio does auto fill as you type and i didn't see that setting in intellij.  But thanks for the post